# Stored procedure to populate Msh Flex Grid / show data when searched

Tags: sql, vb6

Ok So this question pertains to VB6 and SQL SERVER 2008.
I currently have a flexgrid on one of my forms that gets populated by a simple stored procedure

```
Create Proc [dbo].[sp_LoadGrid]
As Begin
Select FirstName, LastName, SEX, DOB, School
from dbo.tblClients
```

Above the flex grid I have 2 textboxes that are to allow the user to search by either first or last name. I've written an if statement to just take whatever letter is written in the txt box and just search the grid (using '%'). Now I have to rewrite it as one stored procedure.
This is what I've gotten but it keeps giving me some weird errors

```
Creat PROC [dbo].[sp_LoadGridSearch]
@FirstName varchar(25) = null
@LastName varchar(25) = null
As Begin
Select FirstName,LastName,DOB,SSN,School
From dbo.TblClients

Where (FirstName like (@FIrstName + '%') or @FirstName is Null) Or
(LastName like (@LastName + '%') or @LastName is Null) 
END
```

Basically what I need it to do is to load the grid, if user puts a letter in either the First or Last name textboxes and presses Search, it will show the clients whos names are starting with that particular letter.

The error I keep getting says sp_cursoropen/sp.cursorprepare.The statement parameter can only be a batch or a stored procedure with a single select, without for Browse, compute by or variable Assignments

Comment: I see you are missing a comma to separate the two parameters, just add `,` before the second parameter declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
create procedure spSearch @fName varchar(25) = null, @lName varchar(25) = null
as
declare @condition varchar(512)
set @condition = '1=1'
if(not @fName is null)
    set @condition = @condition + ' and FirstName like ''' + @fName + '%'''
if(not @lName is null)
    set @condition = @condition + ' and LastName like ''' + @lName + '%'''
exec('select FirstName,LastName,DOB,SSN,School from dbo.TblClients where ' + @condition)
GO
```